# Align ProgressBar horizontal to top (remove gap)

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to put a horizontal progress bar at the top of my frame. But there seems to be padding that I simply have been unable to remove. Any help?

[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/flv_progress_bar"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
             android:indeterminateOnly="true"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="top"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pork'n'Bunny's answer worked API level 16 and up devices. This solution worked in all devices.
Just push it by 6dp up in XML.

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp" />
```

Comment: How robust would this be against changes in the default styles? Are they guaranteed to look and work the same for all eternity or could they theoretically replace them at any time with something where pushing it up 6 pixels would create problems (e.g. an invisible progress bar)?

Comment: This does not work on every device. On Galaxy S6, even with a `-6dp` top margin, white space above the progress bar is still visible.

Comment: a better solution is
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" android:layout_height="4dp"/>

Answer (score 4):

from the looks of it, I think its caused by the image used in the default styling

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

(the image I'm referring to is this one: `@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo` and `@android:drawable/progress_horizontal_holo_dark` )

These images have a lot of canvas background; therefore its showing this gap.

My recommendation:

use a custom image to style you PregressBar. One which doesn't have much canvas spacing.

[image]

Comment: This is ultimately the right answer. I'll have to edit a version of all of the holo drawable (9 patches) to get rid of the padding.

Answer (score 4):

A complete solution to this problem would be as follows. Just in case if someone needs code fragments, this is what I did.

1. Copied all the 8 indeterminate horizontal progressbar drawables
2. Edited the drawables using some image manipulator and remove unnecessary paddings
3. Copied the drawable XML named progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo.xml from android platform
4. Copied the style Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal and its parents
5. Set the style and min_height manually in the layout

Here is the progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo.xml

```
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo1" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo2" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo3" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo4" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo5" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo6" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo7" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo8" android:duration="50" />
```

Style resources copied to my local styles file.

```
<style name="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:attr/textAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">3500</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo</item>
</style>
```

And finally, set min height to 4dp in my local layout file.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:minHeight="4dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo" />
```

Comment: Thanks Subin! I hasn't actually set about doing this yet because I wasn't sure how much beyond editing the one drawable would it take to do, now we all know. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The question is about `?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` and not `@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`

Answer (score 2):

Came up with another solution since the drawable is working as intended in the screenshot. Just push it by 6dp up.

```
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.fwv_progress);
    mProgress.animate().withLayer().yBy(-6.0f*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density).setDuration(0).start();
```

Comment: It works only API level 16 and up.. Is there any way to fix for API 8 and above ?

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is with height attribute. try setting the layout height to some value

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            />
```

Comment: If that is the case then you should change the drawables to customised ones in your styles file    



<style name="Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">Customised drawable</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">Customised drawable</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
    </style>